# Is it possible to declare constant variables outside a class component in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, class, react-hooks, constants

I am attempting to create the following constant variables outside my class component in react native:

```
import { Component, useState } from 'react';

const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
    

class NotificationScreen extends Component {
```

but the following error pops up when running app:

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might...
```

Is there a way to use constant variables in a class?

Comment: You are breaking the rules of hooks. React hooks are only valid in functional components or other custom react hooks. React hooks have nothing to do with `const` variable declarations, these are standard javascript. They can be declared just about anywhere. What is the issue you are trying to solve for?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `state` using Hooks in-class component that's why you are getting error. You can use Hooks in only functional components and within it only but not outside of its scope as constant.

You can surely define constants outside of class and can use it but it would only be `static` data like `BaseURL` of an HTTP request or user types etc but if you have to use `state`, you would need to define it within the class.

You can achieve it using `Hooks` like

```
import { Component, useState } from 'react';

function NotificationScreen(props) {

  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false); 
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

}
```

If you want to use class then you can achieve it like

```
import { Component, useState } from 'react';

class NotificationScreen extends Component {

  state = { isEnabled : false } 

  toggleSwitch = () => {
    this.setState({ isEnabled: !this.state.isEnabled }); 
  }    
}
```

Comment: I know this addresses the obvious error in hook usage, but does it answer the OP's question "Is there a way to use constant variables in a class?"

Comment: @DrewReese I have tried to answer it and updated it

Answer (score 0):

In class based components you can directly use state as `this.state` instead of `useState`. `useState` is for functional components.

So, in your case,

```
class NotificationScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    isEnabled: false
  }

  toggleSwitch = ()=>{
    this.setState(prevState => ({isEnabled: !prevState.isEnabled}))
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <button onPress={this.toggleSwitch}>Press Me!</button>
    )
  }
```

or if you want a global state you will have to use something like [redux](https://redux.js.org)

Comment: Thanks. Please click accept tick mark if it worked. consider upvoting too :)